# C function printing out additional values

Tags: c

I used the below C code in a question which asked to reverse the given array.

But it is outputing some additional values.

Please tell if there's a mistake in code.

Edit : Code passed all test cases after a newline after every test case, but I am still wondering why I was getting those additional values as output. Can any CS major explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t>0){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int arr[n];
        
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }
        
        for(int p = n-1; p>0; p--){
            printf("%d ", arr[p]);
        }
        printf("%d", arr[0]);
        t--;
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
84
86 77 15 93 35 86 92 49 21 62 27 90 59 63 26 40 26 72 36 11 68 67 29 82 30 62 23 67 35 29 2 22 58 69 67 93 56 11 42 29 73 21 19 84 37 98 24 15 70 13 26 91 80 56 73 62 70 96 81 5 25 84 27 36 5 46 29 13 57 24 95 82 45 14 67 34 64 43 50 87 8 76 78 88
```

Expected Output :

```
88 78 76 8 87 50 43 64 34 67 14 45 82 95 24 57 13 29 46 5 36 27 84 25 5 81 96 70 62 73 56 80 91 26 13 70 15 24 98 37 84 19 21 73 29 42 11 56 93 67 69 58 22 2 29 35 67 23 62 30 82 29 67 68 11 36 72 26 40 26 63 59 90 27 62 21 49 92 86 35 93 15 77 86
```

My Output :

```
88 78 76 8 87 50 43 64 34 67 14 45 82 95 24 57 13 29 46 5 36 27 84 25 5 81 96 70 62 73 56 80 91 26 13 70 15 24 98 37 84 19 21 73 29 42 11 56 93 67 69 58 22 2 29 35 67 23 62 30 82 29 67 68 11 36 72 26 40 26 63 59 90 27 62 21 49 92 86 35 93 15 77 8624 64 34 0 93 50 41 28 64 88 79 55 21 51 46 45 18 ...
```

Comment: Can't reproduce (although I only input 5 not 84).

Comment: Not reproducible even with exact inputs

Comment: You can go to this [link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reverse-an-array/0#) to chekout the question.

Comment: Re the link: you aren't reversing an array, but printing it in reverse. Are you sure this is the code that output that result?

Comment: @mradulchourasiya can you reproduce this with a shorter input like `1 5 11 22 33 44 55`? I think the code you run is not the code you show here.

Comment: @WeatherVane Question asked to print the array in reverse, so I just printed in reverse, my concern is about the additional values I am getting as Output.

Comment: "*For each testcase, **in a new line**, print the array in reverse order.*" --- so just add '\n' to the last number.

Comment: @WeatherVane The code does not break on entering small test case but when large input is given it breaks.